# CKeditor Paste Problem

Tags: php, ckeditor, html

I'm using a ckEditor in a project I'm working on, and supposedly the problem of pasting content is solved (paste without the html tags) in version 3.1

I'm using version 3.6.1 and I'm still having the same problem, if I paste from word or any other program, the html tags are still appearing. Anyone has any idea how to fix that problem?

By the way I'm using the ckeditor on Zend Forms ...

Thanks

Comment: Paste into a text editor first (such as Notepad) and copy that into CK or use TinyMCE

Comment: tried to that, it didn't work

Comment: Didn't work? Copying and pasting into a plain text editor such as Notepad __will__ remove the HTML. If you then copy everything _from_ the text editor again and then paste that into CKEditor you will have no HTML tags in your content. I have used FCKeditor and CKEditor for years and my team of developers and our clients use this technique near everyday. So it does work and you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think the problem is that we're trying to copy the data from a document on Google DOCS. Where ever I try to paste the material, it is pasted the same way it was formatted on Google DOCS. But when I tried getting the material from another source, it would work fine, although I'm still can't get rid of the html tags, even when I click on the "Paste as Plain Text" button and paste it there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turn off smart quotes in MSWord before you do the copy. I agree with earlier comments we use ckeditor extensiveley with zend fwork and have never had an issue. Notepad++ is also a helpful ally. You can do a quick search and replace on the html tags before pasting.